# Excluding directories in find

Tags: find

`find` is always a complete mystery to me whenever I use it; I just want to exclude everything under `/mnt` (I am in bash on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL so don't want it to search in the Windows space) from my search, but `find` just blunders into those directories completely ignoring me. I found syntax from this page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command and tried all variations - all failed.

```
sudo find / -name 'git-credential-manager*' -not -path '/mnt/*'
sudo find / -name 'git-credential-manager*' ! -path '/mnt/*'
sudo find / -name 'git-credential-manager*' ! -path '*/mnt/*'
```

When I do this, it just blunders into `/mnt` and throws errors (which is really frustrating as the syntax above looks clear, and the stackoverflow page syntax seems correct):

```
find: ‘/mnt/d/$RECYCLE.BIN/New folder’: Permission denied
find: ‘/mnt/d/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-18’: Permission denied
```

Can someone show me how to stop `find` from ignoring my directory exclusion switches?

Answer (score 17):

Find's `-path` doesn't exclude paths, it means "do not report any matches whose name matches this path". It will still descend into the directories and will search them. What you want is `-prune` (from `man find`):

```
       -prune True;  if  the file is a directory, do not descend into it.  If
              -depth is given, then -prune has no  effect.   Because  -delete
              implies  -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete to‐
              gether.  For example, to skip the directory src/emacs  and  all
              files  and  directories  under  it,  and print the names of the
              other files found, do something like this:
                  find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
```

So, you want:

```
sudo find / -path '/mnt/*' -prune -name 'git-credential-manager*'
```

Although, based on what you're trying to exclude, it might be easier to use `-mount` (GNU `find`) or `-xdev` (others):

From `man find`:

> `-mount` Don't descend directories on other filesystems.  An alternate name for `-xdev`, for compatibility with some other versions of find.

So:

```
sudo find / -mount -name 'git-credential-manager*'
```

Comment: The `-mount` switch works for me perfectly. The only problem with the `find` man page is that it is crazy long and complex, but `find` is quite a complex app I guess. Thanks for the useful options like prune etc. 

Comment: @YorSubs It is entirely normal that you don't easily get it! I have been using various flavors of Linux as my main (only) operating system at work and home since 1998, and I spend most of my time in the command line. I _still_ don't fully grasp all the intricacies of `find`.

Comment: @terdon Imagine developing it...

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't ignore the option. The `-path` predicate is evaluated for each and every file encountered, and for the files in that tree, it just fails. It doesn't affect how `find` walks the directory tree, and you could have something like `find . ! -path "./foo/*" -o -name '*.txt'` which would match everything outside `foo`, but also files matching `*.txt` within it.

The [GNU man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/findutils/find.1.en.html) is rather clear on what to do here, use `-prune` instead:

> `-path pattern`
> ...  To ignore a whole directory tree, use `-prune` rather than checking every file in the tree.  For example, to skip the directory `src/emacs` and all files and directories under it, and print the names of the other files found, do something like this:
>
> ```
> find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
> ```